# Sails' Model.findOrCreate to return the query result in a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, asynchronous, async-await, sails.js

I receive from the frontend an array of item names `itemsNames`. I check if the items are already in the DB or new records should be created. I wrote the following for-loop. I want the loop to `await` until each query is executed, and return each item to a list to later on do some more processes. If I remove the .exec() method, the query returns the created or found item. How can I expose the created item and make the for-loop await until each registry is checked? I want to have the registry of created or already existing items. In the following example screenshot all items were new.

The for-loop:

```
  let dbList;

  for (var i = 0; i < itemsNames.length; i++) {
    let itemsNames= itemsNames[i];
    dbList+= await Item.findOrCreate({ name: itemsNames}, { name: itemsNames})
    .exec( (err, item, wasCreated) => {
      if (err) {
        throw 'Unavailable';
      }
      if(wasCreated) {
        sails.log('Created a new Item: ' + item.name);
      } else {
        sails.log('Found the existing Item: ' + item.name);
      }
      return item;
    });
    console.log('returned from findOrCreate Items: ' + i + ' ' + dbList);
  }

  console.log('Loop end');

  return dbList;
```

This is the Console output:

[image]

I am using Sails 1.2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `findOrCreate` does not accept arrays as parameters you, indeed, need to loop through each item. This is best done using [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3) module. Also mentioned [here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/4994#issuecomment-39864721).

To install async run `npm i async --save` in the project root.
You can then `const async = require('async');` or you can add it as a global module by modifing `config/globals.js`. In `globals.js` change `async: false,` to `async: require('async'),`.

Here is a simple [async.map](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#map) code that will do what you want:

```
async.map(
    items, // your items array [{"name": "foo"}, {"name": "bar"}, ...]
    (item, cb) => Item
        .findOrCreate(item, item)
        .exec((err, item, created) => cb(err, {item, created})),
    (err, data) => console.log(err || data) // data will contain array of data in {item: Item, created: true/false} format
);
```

If you're looking to make this functionality in to a controller action here is an example:

```
findOrCreateMultiple(req, res) {
    async.map(
        req.param('items'),
        (item, cb) => Item
            .findOrCreate(item, item)
            .exec((err, item, created) => cb(err, {item, created})),
        (err, data) => {
            if (err) return res.serverError(err);
            res.json(data);
        }
    );
}
```

You send:

```
{
    "items": [{"name": "foo"}, {"name": "bar"}, {"name": "biz"}]
}
```

foo and bar already existed, biz was created.
Response:

```
[
  {
    "item": {
      "createdAt": 1589379855770,
      "updatedAt": 1589379855770,
      "id": 1,
      "name": "foo"
    },
    "created": false
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "createdAt": 1589379855774,
      "updatedAt": 1589379855774,
      "id": 2,
      "name": "bar"
    },
    "created": false
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "createdAt": 1589380146471,
      "updatedAt": 1589380146471,
      "id": 3,
      "name": "biz"
    },
    "created": true
  }
]
```